# Win32 "C" Unhandled Exception breaks at wrong location

Tags: c, winapi, floating-point, visual-studio-debugging, unhandled-exception

This has been puzzling me for the last several days!

We have an application where we're running into a divide-by-zero.  That application is purposely built to raise exceptions in such cases, with a call to the  _controlfp_s function to change the masks on floating point exceptions.

Now, when running into a divide-by-zero on pretty much all of our machines, Visual Studio 2005 debugger breaks at the proper location within our source files.  However, on 1 machine, the break location is all over the place and appears to be irrelevant to the actual cause of the break.  So as a test, I built a simple C win32 program with just the following lines of code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float temp1, temp2, temp3;
    unsigned int control;

    _controlfp_s(&control, (_EM_UNDERFLOW + _EM_INEXACT, _MCW_EM);

    temp1=1.0;
    temp2=0.0;
    temp3=temp1/temp2;

    return 0;
}
```

On all those "good" machines, the code does break at temp3.  However, on the bad machine, the code breaks at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\tidtable.c

function:

__set_flsgetvalue()

Looking at the registers as I step through the assembly code, everything looks fine until I hit the "fstp" instruction... then all the registers seem to be messed up (vs looking as expected on a good machine).  When comparing the stack on the good vs bad, I also see  stack entries on the bad machine, which I don't see on the good one...

I'm skipping quite a few details here in an attempt to keep this first pass short... but I'll add up more if someone is so kind as to try to help.

Notes:
OS Win7 x64, running all the latest VS2005 Service Packs.  Compared to a similar (working) machine running same software and service packs.  Getting same weird behavior when running on VS2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: many of these conditions aren't detected right away but well after the fact when some operation finds its in a bad state. This behavior may very well be CPU specific.

Comment: Also note that, in total desperation, I have uninstalled/re-installed everything related to Visual Studio.  Same results, of course.

Comment: the problem is... the break works perfectly fine on just about every single machine I tested (win 7 x64, win server 2008 R2, XP) with various CPU... and it always works as expected.  This code is pretty old and has always worked.  I thought it could be something in the computer BIOS or something... some MB/CPU machine specific optimization that messed up the handling... but I'm still getting the same results when turning off all but 1 cpu and all optimization set through the BIOS.

Comment: Also, I believe what you're saying is true if the application doesn't specifically call _controlfp_s... at which point, some piece of code may react unexpectedly to some bad float value... but when specifically calling _controlfp_s, I believe this forces the exception to be thrown at as it's being detected... as seen when stepping through the assembly code on all good machines.

Comment: Well Doug (cause you're the only one that took a shot at it)... I thought you'd be interested in my additional test results.  I've taken the following troubleshooting steps:

Comment: 1- Made a disk image of the original HP disk onto a spare disk and restored factory image.
2- Only installed Visual Studio 2005 Pro - C++ portion.
3- Tested code above, still failed.
4- Updated all service packs on Windows and tested code above.  Failed.
5- Updated all service packs on Studio 2005 and tested code above. Failed.
6- Uninstalled all bloatware and tested code above. Failed.
7- Updated BIOS and firmware and tested code above. Failed.
8- Installed Visual Studio 2010 and tested code above. Failed.

Comment: Then... I decided to take my spare imaged disk and install it on a similar but slightly older HP computer we have, with different hardware.

I went through the installation process fine, even though it was using the recovery partition of my newer machine.  On that machine, I simply installed the OS and Visual Studio 2005 Pro - C++ portion.  No service packs whatsoever (even if Studio 2005 requires an update for "vista") and the code worked as expected!!

So it DOES appear that it's hardware related... however, I do think it's a bug and not a fundamental design difference.

Comment: With this knowledge, I have now posted this on HP's website, as my machines are from HP.

Sorry... had to split up all these answers.  Alternative was to "Answer Your Question", which didn't seem right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow!

After showing this post to a friend... he found an intel document showing very similar symptoms about some of their cpu's... I then found the exact document that applied to our specific CPU (intel i5-2500) here:

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/2nd-gen-core-deskt...

See errata BJ1

This pretty much exactly describes what I'm running into!  I never (seriously) thought it would be an issue at THAT level!